# XPath Predicate - Access the origin node from selectSingleNode

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to know if there is a way to obtain the value of the origin node when doing a query.

I have an XPath query using selectSingleNode. I would like to be able to create a predicate where the test is against a value from the node being searched.

For example...

`node.selectSingleNode("//node1/node2[anotherNode=origin()/originNode]/theReturningNode")`

The *origin()* in this case is the node used in the *selectSingleNode*

Many Thanks

Comment: I guess you're using the DOM method node.selectSingleNode() and therefore you're probably using XPath 1.0. There are certainly solutions if you switch to an XPath processor that implements a more up-to-date version of XPath.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a thing in XSLT (called `current()`), but it does not exist in XPath.

You have to build your XPath expression dynamically in this case:

```
"//node1/node2[anotherNode = '" + originNode.text + "']/theReturningNode"
```

Beware that this will produce invalid XPath (and therefore run-time errors) when `originNode.text` contains single quotes. This [can be worked around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57639969/18771) if necessary. Different work-arounds apply to XPath 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Yes, we're aware of that...and I assumed there was no means to do this, but wanted to confirm this was 100%.

Comment: Also be aware that constructing an XPath expression using string concatenation exposes you to injection attacks. It's better if you can to use a variable, and supply the variable's value using an API.

Comment: This is not always possible, but when it is, it's of course the preferred approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you install an XPath processor such as Saxon that implements an up-to-date version of XPath, then you can use the query

```
let $origin := . return
    //node1/node2[anotherNode=$origin/originNode]/theReturningNode
```

In fact some XPath 1.0 processors will allow you to run the query

```
//node1/node2[anotherNode=$origin/originNode]/theReturningNode
```

supplying the value of $origin as an external parameter via API.

You probably won't be able to use the DOM's `selectSingleNode` method, but other APIs are available (e.g. JAXP).

Comment: Unfortunately we're using the DOMDocument so that won't be available.

Comment: Both the options I suggested (Saxon or JAXP) will work fine with DOM documents.

Comment: Sure they will! However we're glued to using the DOMDocument (XmlDocument) object model....this just won't work.